# Django process a form that dynamically adds fields, correct approach

Tags: django, forms

Ive been reading about this in SO and I find the answers are kind of specific to the case that is being asked. 
My case is this one:

I need to create a form that represents a **Receipt**. Inside it, the user can dynamically add **Items** (In the backend, each Item has a FK to the Receipt the belong to).

So, should each **Item** be represented by a form? (each Item has several fields I'd like to validate on the backend) This means adding forms dynamically in the front ... and the forms added would be inside the "parent" form that represents the **Receipt** ... is this correct? How can I achieve that? how do I process it in the backend?

Or ... maybe I can just build the Html and Js without any relation to a Django form. Then on the backend, validate the fields "artifically" with `bleach` and try to figure out what data goes to the **Receipt**, how many **Items** where added and create the corresponding **Items** objects based on what I can read from `cleaned_data`... but this seems complex too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what Django's [inlineformset_factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/models/) and the [django-dynamic-formsert](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset) package are made for. The inline formsets would represent the **Items** and each inline formset would be linked to a parent **Receipt**. See [Inline Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) for more info.